# How do I change red background of my testng test results html page ? Its hurting my eyes

Tags: unit-testing, testng

When I open the test results of my testng tests, the html page has red background for tests that have failed. The red is too glaring for my eyes. Is there a css config or property that I can change to change this red color to something else for all tests ?????

It would be very helpful.

Environment : linux

Testng framework : 6.3.2beta

thanks.

Comment: We need to know what environment you're running these tests in, using what framework, etc

Comment: you could set the background to a different color if you have access to the code, with **pure html** or **CSS**. But you need to specify more, even with a little bit of code.

Comment: Make the tests pass and you won't have any problems with an eye-hurting red color ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest version, which has new reports:

http://beust.com/weblog/2012/01/01/ushering-testng-into-the-new-year/

Answer (score 1):

It's eye-hurting on purpose. The way to fix it is to make your tests pass, you can then enjoy a blissful quiet green and sleep well at night.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's eye-hurting on purpose, more because I'm terrible at writing HTML and CSS code. Although I hope to have improved a bit with the new generation of reports (see the link I posted in another comment).

Comment: I don't know, I quite like the idea of having a harsh fail page: that pushes to fix the tests as quickly as possible - a bit like some agile teams that force people who break the build to wear a ridiculous hat all day :)